# Factory Design Pattern implementation in console application

Tags: c#, console-application, factory, factory-pattern

I am new to programming and learning through online stuff and you guys, nowadays! I am reading about Factory Design Pattern and tried to implement in the very basic project, I have a solution that has two projects one projects contain interfaces, and the other contains implementation, I have read about factories but unfortunately, I have no idea how to implement in my project, In one project, I have 2 interfaces IBasicCars and ILuxuryCars, IluxuryCars implementing IBasicCars and then in the second project I have a class that inherits from ILuxuryCars and implement all of its methods and IBasicCars methods and properties, here is my code for that class.

```
    public class LuxuryCars : ILuxuryCar
{            
    

    private string _color { get; set; }
    public string Color
    {
        get
        {
            return _color;
        }
        set
        {
            _color = value;
        }
    }

    private int _model { get; set; }
    public int Model
    {
        get
        {
            return _model;
        }
        set
        {
            _model = value;
        }
    }


    private string _make { get; set; }
    public string Make
    {
        get
        {
            return _make;
        }
        set
        {
            _make = value;
        }
    }

    public void Break()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the basic function of all cars !!!");
    }

    public void CruiseControl()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the luxury feature for luxury cars !!!");
    }

    public void Drive()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the basic function of all cars !!!");
    }

    public void Navigation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the luxury feature for luxury cars !!!");
    }

    public void Park()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the basic function of all cars !!!");
    }
}
```

now I have another class "FactoryObject" in that project that has nothing in it right now, can someone please tell me to do I implement the factory design pattern?

that is how I am calling these methods in main method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        ILuxuryCar lc = new LuxuryCars();


        lc.Color = "Black";
        lc.Make = "Honda";
        lc.Model = 2007;


        Console.WriteLine("Car color is: {0} Made by: {1} Model is: {2}", lc.Color, lc.Make, lc.Model);
        lc.Navigation();
        lc.CruiseControl();
        lc.Break();
        lc.Drive();
        lc.Park();

        Console.WriteLine();

        IBasicCar b = new LuxuryCars();

        b.Color = "Red";
        b.Make = "Alto";
        b.Model = 2019;


        Console.WriteLine("Car color is: {0} Made by: {1} Model is: {2}", lc.Color, lc.Make, lc.Model);
        lc.Break();
        lc.Drive();
        lc.Park();



        Console.ReadLine();



    }
```

Comment: Î suppose instead of writing `new LuxureCars()` within your `Main`, you should do that within the factory, because it´s the job of the factory to create other objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple factory could be

```
public interface ICarFactory{
     ICar Create();
}
public class BasicCarFactory : ICarFactory{
    public ICar Create() => new BasicCar();
}
public class LuxuryCarFactory : ICarFactory{
    public ICar Create() => new LuxuryCar();
}
```

This makes it more complicated to create a car, but the important bit is that components that need to create new car objects can do so without knowing what kind of car is created.

You might for example check the license at startup, and depending on the license create different factories that you hand of to all the other components. This way you have the license check at one single place, instead of spread out over different components.

In simple cases you might not need a separate inteface, a `Func<ICar>` might be sufficient.